# Formatting dates to compare

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

Okay so I have this SwiftUI project and I'm lost in how to get this to work.

1. I'm using a 2020 api for calendar because I can't find one that's free for the current year - + 3
2. I can't figure out why my date won't format as I'm requesting so I can get the date to match formats to let me know if it's a holiday or not.

3 Here's my code below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dayChosen = Date()
    let currentDate = Date()
    let dateComponent = DateComponents(year:2020)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchHolidays()
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            DatePicker("Select a date", selection: $dayChosen, in: currentDate...,displayedComponents: .date).datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            Text("Your current date is \(dayChosen)")
            let modDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(dayChosen)")
            
            let filtered = fetch.dataArray.filter {
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
                return dateFormatter.date(from: $0.dateMonth+"/"+$0.dateDay+"/2022") == modDate
            }
           
            if let holiday = filtered.first{
                let _ = print("\(modDate)")
                
                Text("This is a holiday around these parts \(holiday.name)")
            }else{
                Text("Eh regular")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

All I'm looking to do here is filter out all of the dates that match the one from the cal selection(which technically should only be one date anyway) and then display it as a holiday or non

Comment: You should be using `Calendar.compare(_:to:toGranularity:)` to compare two days. Formatting dates to String just for comparison is just not a good idea. Make sure you have time zones for date picker and calendar set to the same value. Otherwise comparing dates won't work.

Comment: @Sulthan care to explain a little more with an example of what you mean? My apologies for being annoying here. I'm just struggling to get this. I'm not even getting my dates to format the same even though I THINK I'm passing them through the formatter correctly.

Comment: @Havic What Sulthan is saying is that you have access to the underlying components which make up each date: formatting those components into a string and comparing strings is a roundabout way to do the comparison when you could be comparing the components directly. It'll be more performant and less likely to run into trouble with the specifics of formatting.